# Integrate $\frac{\arctan x}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

$$\int \frac{\arctan
(x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx$$

(I have a constant in front of the integral, but I figure it just distributes to each of the terms in the end answer, and simplified it for now).

I figured it would be a chance for using integration by parts. I let $u=\arctan x, du=\frac{1}{x^2+1}, dv=\frac{1}{x^2}, v=\frac{-1}{x}$.

I get then $$\frac{-\arctan (x)}{x} -\int\left( -\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx$$ I cancel out the negatives in front of the integral and what's in front of the 1.

So I do partial fractions, and find that $\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{(x^2+1)}$. I get that A=1 and B=-1 by letting x=0 and x=1, respectively.

So I have the $\arctan (x)$, and $\int\left( -\frac{1}{1+x^2} ,dx\right)$, simple enough, I thought, which generates $\ln |x|$ and $-\arctan (x)$. Somewhere, this must be wrong, but I can't see where. Please help!

Comment: Hint: use by parts with h first function arctanx and second function $1/x^2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please improve formatting by using MathJax and clarify *where* you have to integrate $\frac{\arctan x}{x^2}$. Such function has a non-integrable singularity of the $\frac{1}{x}$ kind at the origin.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is my first time posting so just getting used to the formatting. I noticed that somehow I missed the denominator when I wrote in the first way, so the first result of integration by parts now is multiplied by the v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int { \frac { \arctan { x }  }{ { x }^{ 2 } } dx } =-\int { \arctan { x } d\left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right)  } =-\frac { \arctan { x }  }{ x } +\int { \frac { dx }{ x\left( { x }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  }  } =\\ =-\frac { \arctan { x }  }{ x } +\int { \left[ \frac { 1 }{ x } -\frac { x }{ { x }^{ 2 }+1 }  \right] dx } =-\frac { \arctan { x }  }{ x } +\int { \frac { dx }{ x } - } \frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \frac { d\left( { x }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  }{ { x }^{ 2 }+1 }  } =\\ =-\frac { \arctan { x }  }{ x } +\ln { \left| x \right| - } \frac { 1 }{ 2 } \ln { \left( { x }^{ 2 }+1 \right) +C } $$

Comment: Oh, so the partial fractions yielded a Bx, where B=-1! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\int{\arctan x/x^2}.dx=\arctan x\int{1/x^2}.dx - \int{(\arctan x)'\int(1/x^2.dx}).dx$

Further to evaluate second integral you can use partial fraction while the first one is trivial.

Comment: Ah thanks @BarryCipra. Corrected

Comment: Ha ha... Many thanks.. @BarryCipra